# What is the terminology for what this method attempts?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullreferenceexception, null-coalescing-operator

I don't know:

1. if this works.
2. if it's a good idea.
3. what it is called in order
   to find out more about it.

But I think the intent is fairly apparent.

```
public static class DebugLogic
{
    public static bool ThrowIfNull = false;

    public static T OrNew<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj != null) return obj;
        else if (ThrowIfNull) throw new ArgumentNullException(//to do...);
        else return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    }
}
```

Intended usage: 
`var customer = order.Sale.OrNew().Customer.OrNew().Name`

What am I doing? Is this insane or helpful? It **seems** helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment and turned it into an answer. And then noticed that JaredPar said it better than me and deleted my answer. (For other's reference I was talking about the `new()` restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the idea of having an `OrNew` method is fine.  Especially if you're striving to make a fluent interface.  However I would change 3 things about it

1. Don't have a hidden flag that controls the behavior (`ThrowIfNull`).  This makes it impossible for someone to read an `OrNew` call an understand what it does.
2. Use a `new` constraint in favor of the less safe `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` call
3. I'd call it something other than `DebugLogic`.  Generally (but not always) extension method containers end with the `Extensions` .

For example

```
public static class LogicExtensions {
  public static T OrNew<T>(this T obj) where T : class, new() {
    if (obj != null) {
      return obj;
    }
    return new T();
  }
}
```

Comment: `ThrowIfNull` also has a race condition if you're changing it before calling `OrNull`. And if you wanted an exception you would get that anyway when you tried to operate on the null object.

Comment: Oh and you could just have `return obj ?? new T();`

Comment: thanks! I made an override with a bool for throwing. I was thinking a global setting would be useful for my own debugging purposes. I'm a beginner and was seeing this as kind of a personal crutch.

Comment: @Ray that is getting even shorter! I thought it was possible but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Am I missing something or resulting object will be essentially lost at the end of `a.b.OrNew().c.d` call? To me it looks like `my.Sale.OrNew()` is intended to populate `my` with a new `Sale` on demand.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're not missing something, the result will be lost. But this type of API is useful for fluent interfaces where either the result is saved or used as another step in the call graph to produce a value.  So the lost value is OK here.

Comment: @Ray I don't understand about a race condition. My intention was to be able to optionally ignore null references in limited situations where I don't have time for more presentation logic. I figured I could "globally" change the setting if I was causing myself more problems than I was avoiding.

Comment: @Benjamin The race condition is only if you were to change the `ThrowIfNull` before each time you call it. I wasn't sure how you were using it.

Comment: @Simon why do you think a global override for that is a bad idea?

Comment: @Benjamin like Jared said, there's no way to know what this function does.  Something somewhere else in the code might have set or unset the flag without your knowledge.  If you want behaviour like that, put it in another argument and have an override with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

The name of this operation is clearly: `DefaultIfNull`

Comment: David what do programmers mean by "default"? I see it often but haven't understood it yet. Does that refer to the result of a customized parameterless constructor? Whatever I establish as being the default? Or just an empty instance of the class? Thanks.